# Allow only AWS Specific HTTP and HTTPS request from security group

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-security-group

I want to turn off the internet connection from EC2 so that the user wont be able to connect to the internet but simultaneously I want to allow internal (Boto/Boto3) HTTP/HTTPS Calls to the AWS. How can I achieve this using security group?

Answer (score 1):

If you are using **ec2-vpc**, it allows you to add separate inbound and outbound rules to your security group but **ec2-classic** supports inbound rules only.

Comment: but i want to allow the boto library's internal htpps calls from ec2 to aws

Answer (score 0):

You can use [AWS IP Address Ranges - Amazon Web Services](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/aws-ip-ranges.html) to obtain a list of IP addresses used by Amazon for each region.

You could add the relevant IP addresses to the Security Group so that only outbound connections to those addresses are permitted.

Alternatively:

- If you wish to access Amazon S3 or Amazon DynamoDB, you can use [VPC Endpoint for Amazon S3](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/new-vpc-endpoint-for-amazon-s3/)
- If you wish to access Amazon EC2, Elastic Load Balancing (ELB), Kinesis Streams, Service Catalog or EC2 Systems Manager, you can use [AWS PrivateLink for AWS Services](https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2017/11/introducing-aws-privatelink-for-aws-services/)

These allow you to route requests from a VPC directly to a service, without going out through an Internet Gateway. The security is enforced by the Route Table (which sends the traffic to a different destination) rather than the Security Group (which blocks traffic).

Comment: i  just want to allow https calls from boto which are mainly for describing state function activity by connecting to the region.

Comment: There is no way for the Amazon VPC to know that application that originated the call. The only thing it can see is traffic coming out of the Amazon EC2 instance. By restricting the IP ranges in the security group, _ALL_ traffic coming out of the instance will be blocked unless it is to those ranges, which will effectively make the Internet inaccessible (except for AWS endpoints). The same goes for using the Endpoints.

Answer (score 0):

Within a VPC, If you have a private Subnet and want your EC2 in private subnet to be able to communicate with Internet you can use NAT Gateway which you have to locate it on a **Public Subnet** of you VPC(with an Internet Routable IP, i.e. Assign an EIP to it) then you will add the NAT to your **Routing Rules** within your **Private Subnet** (Destination could be 0.0.0.0/0 with Target of NAT) where your EC2 from it's private subnet can Route traffic to the NAT Gateway, located on the Public Subnet. However, please note behind the NAT(Which is Routable to Internet Gateway) it is your EC2 instance that can Initiate the communication with the services on the Internet. Just like any other systems behind a NAT, Internet can not initiate a communication to Internal network unless it is a response to initiated communication by your EC2 Instance. If you have a Library on the EC2 instance behind a NAT Gateway then you can start communicating externally.
PS: You can define NACL Rules for the Subnet which you are placing your NAT Gateway on to further harden Network Access.